# Sending comma separated input params into the stored proc and looping each param in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple stored procedure with comma separated input params. I will send Database Names in Json or Comma separated values.
Like  DB1,DB2,DB3 etc..;
When ever I send that parameter will be loading that table in each of the Database.
I'm looking for loop condition and splitting values.

```
EXEC   student_info (DBName = 'DB1,DB2,DB3,DB')

    DELIMITER &&  
    ALTER PROCEDURE student_info (IN DBName varchar(100))  
    BEGIN  
     **Splitting comma separated**
     **loop condition**  
        INSERT INTO @DBName.tbl_student(Name,Class)
        SELECT Name,Class FROM DB.student_info  ;  

    END &&  
    DELIMITER ;
```

What is the best way?

Comment: Changing your question in a material way after people have spent time answering the original question is disrespectful of people's time. You have been using this site for 11 years according to your profile, so you should know better!

Comment: yes @BillKarwin I agree with it my apologies   and it won't repeat again

Answer (score 1):

You need to use prepared statements (see: [PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html))

```sql
drop procedure if exists student_info;
DELIMITER &&  
CREATE PROCEDURE student_info(IN dbname varchar(100))  
BEGIN  
    declare a CHAR(16);
    declare s VARCHAR(400);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    with recursive cte as (
      select 
         @dbname as s1,
         substring_index(substring_index(@dbname,',',1),',',-1) as s2, 
         1 as x
      union all
      select 
         s1, 
         substring_index(substring_index(s1,',',x+1),',',-1), 
         x+1
      from cte 
      where x< (select length(s1)-length(replace(s1,',',''))+1)
      )
      select s2 from cte;

    open cur1;
     
    read_loop: loop
        fetch cur1 into a;
        set @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',a,'.tbl_student(Name,Class) SELECT Name,Class FROM DB.student_info  ');
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM  @s;
        execute stmt1 ;
        deallocate prepare stmt1;
    END loop;

    close cur1;
END &&  
DELIMITER ;
```

I tested with this:

```sql
drop table if exists DB1.tbl_student;
drop table if exists DB2.tbl_student;
drop table if exists DB3.tbl_student;
drop table if exists DB.tbl_student;
drop table if exists DB.student_info;
create table DB.tbl_student(name varchar(100),class varchar(100));
create table DB1.tbl_student(name varchar(100),class varchar(100));
create table DB2.tbl_student(name varchar(100),class varchar(100));
create table DB3.tbl_student(name varchar(100),class varchar(100));

create table DB.student_info(name varchar(100),class varchar(100));
insert into DB.student_info values ('Willem', 'Mathematics');
insert into DB.student_info values ('John', 'Mathematics');
insert into DB.student_info values ('Trudy', 'Mathematics');

CALL   student_info ('DB1,DB2,DB3,DB');
```

After this the data checked to be copied from `student_info` to the different `tbl_student` tables.

NOTE:
I would not create those tables, and copy the data, but I would use a view:

```sql
create view db1.tbl_student as select name,class from db.student_info;
```

When you create a view, there is no need to copy the data to the other database, because this view will be updated automatically when records in the table `db.student_info` are updated/deleted or inserted.

P.S. Above was testen on MySQL 8.x.  Some functionality that is not available in earlier versions of MySQL (like `WITH`) is used.

Comment: i @luuk thanks for the great answer and explanation but here I'm using  version 5.7.38 . Can you please suggest code in that version

Answer (score 0):

(Answer to the original question, before the edit)

Use `FIND_IN_SET` instead of a loop

```
SELECT Name,Class 
FROM student_info 
where FIND_IN_SET(ID, studentID);
```

Comment: ID's input will come in (100,101,102,103,104,105). I need to make it  separate values  and loop through the where condition

Comment: @mohan111 This answer doesn't loop because it doesn't need to, it finds all the rows in one step.

Comment: @slaakso please find the updated  question

Comment: Please use a separate question instead of changing the original.